# How to fix AVD Manager unable to detect device even though adb commands work on PC?

Tags: avd-manager

I am trying to connect my Google Nexus 5 so that I can debug my Xamarin code from Visual Studio with it.

I have downloaded all the drivers and all that. When I type in `adb -d devices` it finds my phone. I can do all sorts of things with it from there, so the phone is for sure connected to the computer.

My problem is how do I get the AVD manager to realize that? It just won't find my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVD is **not** in charge for real devices.

There is a Step-by-Step Tutorial from Xamarin for Nexus devices:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_with_xamarin_android/

If this won't work, try to stop your Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The "V" in *AVD Manager* stands for *virtual*, which is your clue that this tool is only for managing virtual devices (i.e. emulator images), not real devices. Accordingly, you shouldn't expect your real device to show up there. You don't need to use AVD Manager at all for debugging, if you're using a real device: the tool you're using should just show a list of devices.